# Ask questions about psychological disorders

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

What is the website to talk and ask about general specific psychological disorders, ask for help or for health and general life tips? If such website exists

Example of psychological disorder:

- avoidant personality disorder
- generalized anxiety disoder
- hypervigilance
- PTSD
- etc

Comment: Cognitive disorders can be discussed, in the clinical/academic sense, on [CogSci.se], but read their help center for an overview of topicality first. For health, see [health.se], and for General life tips, see [lifehacks.se]. Again, read all the respective help centers first, so you know the rules *before* you ask your first question.

Comment: Thanks - I read a similar question about asking for a website so I took my chance and I get downvoted - o.O. I jsut won't ask again. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Don’t worry about the downvote. Meta.se is curmudgeonly. Unless you get a few, downvotes don’t mean much here. Here, I’ll upvote you to cancel it out.

Comment: Oh ok thank you - I have a tendency to get paranoid when I see -1 :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General questions about mental disorders and psychological health can be asked at [Cognitive Sciences.SE](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/), as @DanBron mentioned. See their [on-topic guidance](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), but note that "[Questions about the behavior of an individual person are off-topic. If you are concerned about a potential medical issue, please seek the advice of a medical professional.](https://cogsci.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/502/why-was-my-self-help-question-closed-as-off-topic)"

General questions on health and medical topics, including psychiatry and psychiatric medications, can be asked at [Health.SE](https://health.stackexchange.com/), but the stack's [Help Center](https://health.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) specifies that, "If your question is requesting personal medical advice, it is off-topic and instead should be directed to your personal physician."

Neither of these sites allow one to "ask for help or for health and general life tips", but you can ask general questions *that can apply to others* and that are not requests or substitutes for professional advice. You could ask, for example, about the side effects of taking Prozac or about the diagnostic criteria for Post-Traumatic Stress Disorder, but you should not ask whether or not *you* should take Prozac or whether or not you have PTSD.